# CAShapeLayer shrink and fade out animation not working correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cashapelayer

I have this circle (that fits inside the letter O which is currently not exactly a circle) and I want it to shrink and regrow, fading out and in.  So I have it shrinking, and fading out, but when it does the animation, the CAShapeLayer moves to the top left of the screen and doesn't stay put in place (which is the objective).  How do I accomplish this?

```
    CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    [circleLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(74.93, 59.5, 31.52, 31.2)] CGPath]];
    [circleLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 green:0.1 blue:0.2 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
    [circleLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 green:0.1 blue:0.2 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];        

    CABasicAnimation* fadeAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    CABasicAnimation* shrinkAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
    fadeAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    fadeAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    fadeAnim.duration = 1.25;
    shrinkAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    shrinkAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.05];
    shrinkAnim.duration = 1.25;
    [circle1 addAnimation:fadeAnim forKey:@"opacity"];
    [circle1 addAnimation:shrinkAnim forKey:@"transform.scale"];
    circle1.opacity = 0.0;
```

Comment: I apologize, I have that first section in another method, and then get a reference to the returned CAShapeLayer stored in circle1.  For all intents and purposes, circleLayer is circle1

Comment: create a UIViewController subclass in xcode........then copy and paste the code I provided in the viewDidLoad method.  So when you run this, what you should see is a little red circle appear, then slowly but surely fade and shrink to the top left of the screen

Comment: change circleLayer to circle1 or vice versa

Comment: And finally, write [[self.view layer] addSublayer:circle1];  before any of the animation code (basically in between the two section).

Comment: so thanks for helping man, really appreciate it..........